# Which Twitter Streaming should I use:public, User or Site?

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

My use case is the following:

I have to 'listen' to the tweets and retweets of a unknown number of users (the users can register in this feature whenever they want) that mention some known users or whenever they use a predefined hashtag. When such a tweet is made, I have to register this action in my database, but I just need to know whenever this happens, I don't care about the content of the tweet.

One important point is that I shouldn't lose any of these tweet events.

Reading through the Twitter API I've found the Streaming API that seems what I should use for my use case, but I get lost when I start reading about limits of users, 1% of tweets, firehose etc

In theory I think I should be using the Site Streaming API, but I'm not really sure and also it is in limited beta. Is it difficult to get access to this Site Streaming? Which are its limitations? Would I be able to receive, for example, tweets for 200.000 users without losing any?

Is there any other approach I should look at?

Answer (score 0):

> that mention some known users or whenever they use a predefined hashtag

This sounds like a public [filter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter) stream would work.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I've readed somewhere that there's a limitation of 5.000 follow users or something similar. Do you know if this is true or have I just invented it?

Comment: The purpose of that is to limit the users to apply the filter to. If you use track, you should get tweets for any user whose tweets contain the hashtag or mentioned user. e.g. track="joemayo,#linqtotwitter" would return tweets with any mentions of joemayo or any hashtag containing #linqtoTwitter.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but my use case should mix both options. I need to track mentions and hashtags, but just for specific users...